# MySQL "zombie"-table: Is it safe to remove a line in information_schema?

Tags: mysql

this is a follow-up on [MySQL "Zombie"-table, cannot delete](https://serverfault.com/questions/516170/) where I asked abot a rogue table in schema mysql.

Long story short:

- I accidently wrote a file general.log to the MySQL datadir
- Removed it later
- mysqldump starts complaining about missing information about table general_log
- cant drop the table
- cant recreate the table and delete it,

Now i found a line in information_schema:

```
mysql> select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'general_log';
+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------------+
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME  | TABLE_TYPE | ENGINE | VERSION | ROW_FORMAT | TABLE_ROWS | AVG_ROW_LENGTH | DATA_LENGTH | MAX_DATA_LENGTH | INDEX_LENGTH | DATA_FREE | AUTO_INCREMENT | CREATE_TIME | UPDATE_TIME | CHECK_TIME | TABLE_COLLATION | CHECKSUM | CREATE_OPTIONS | TABLE_COMMENT |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------------+
| NULL          | mysql        | general_log | BASE TABLE | CSV    |      10 | Dynamic    |          2 |              0 |           0 |               0 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | NULL        | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |     NULL |                | General log   |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to delete that line.

**Would that be safe?

Is there more information in other tables related to this entry?**

Comment: I honestly wouldn't touch anything in the information_schema manually.

Comment: Even if i know there is no table tied to this? I can do that in a test environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a zombie table as you call it.

When mysql was installed, the table `mysql.general_log` was included.

It uses the [**CSV storage engine**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/csv-storage-engine.html).

The two files that represent it are

- `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.frm`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.CSV`

You have the option to enable general logging in that table. Personally, I would never use it as a CSV table. I would convert it to MyISAM and index it. Then, activate it so that I can query the table by datetime and locate SQL commands and users in time ranges.

I have many posts in the DBA StackExchange on how to set it up and use it. Here are a few:

- `Dec 27, 2011` : [How to do MySQL User Accounting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9776/877)
- `Jan 08, 2012` : [How to enable MySQL general log?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10346/877)
- `Feb 11, 2012` : [MySQL general log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12672/877)

FOR EMPHASIS : That is not a phantom table. It's real. Simply run in the mysql client:

```
SHOW CREATE TTABLE mysql.general_log\G
```

or this in the OS

```
ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.*
```

Now, it mysqldump is complaining about that table, chances are you must have delete the `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.CSV` file and left the other file `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.frm` alone. There are two solutions:

## SOLUTION #1 : Create the CSV file again

```
echo -n > /var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.CSV
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.CSV
```

## SOLUTION #2 : Delete the `.frm` file

```
rm -f /var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.frm
```

CAVEAT: Once you delete `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.frm`, you cannot make a general log table until you do this:

```
CREATE TABLE `general_log` (
    `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
    `thread_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log';
```

If you never intend to use the general log as table, then deleting it should not be a problem.